# Get SSL Certificate on web service C#

Tags: c#, web-services, x509certificate

I have created a webservice in which I'm getting a certificate from store as follows

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly & OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates = (X509CertificateCollection)certStore.Certificates;



            X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate();
            foreach (X509Certificate Cert in clientCertificates)
            {
                if (Cert.Issuer.Contains("O=Neutralus,"))
                {
                    certificate = Cert;
                }
            }
```

this works fine when I test web service and gets a certificate for me but when i deploy this service and access it from other computer it gives me following error

> A client certificate was not found in the SSL stream. The client could not be authenticated.

I have installed certificate on both computers and tried `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` and all StoreName.

Comment: This means that the certificate is not installed on a system where you deployed the application.

Comment: when i run service on system where i deployed it.it loads certificate

Comment: try to change the store name to **root** or to the store where you have installed the certificate.